# Okta SAML2 Single Logout issue

Tags: .net, saml, okta

ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 - Single Logout

I have Okta as IdP and one SP setup. SSO works great between them. Single Logout does not work for me. I got                 the 403 unauthorized error

SingleLogout endpoint is the same as in example (Source from ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 - TestWebApp)

Have you seen anything like it? I ran out of ideas what could be done in this case.

```
public ActionResult SingleLogout()
{
            Saml2StatusCodes status;
            var requestBinding = new Saml2PostBinding();
            var logoutRequest = new Saml2LogoutRequest(config, ClaimsPrincipal.Current);
            try
            {
                requestBinding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), logoutRequest);
                status = Saml2StatusCodes.Success;
                logoutRequest.DeleteSession();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                // log exception
                Debug.WriteLine("SingleLogout error: " + exc.ToString());
                status = Saml2StatusCodes.RequestDenied;
            }

            var responsebinding = new Saml2PostBinding();
            responsebinding.RelayState = requestBinding.RelayState;
            var saml2LogoutResponse = new Saml2LogoutResponse(config)
            {
                InResponseToAsString = logoutRequest.IdAsString,
                Status = status,
            };            
            return responsebinding.Bind(saml2LogoutResponse).ToActionResult();

}
```